# cordova-plugin-camera: Getting "No Image Selected" error on Android 4.4 device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm working on an hybrid mobile app build with Ionic 1.x. Currently I'm dealing with an weird behavior related to `cordova-plugin-camera` on devices running Android 4.4 (KitKat - Also tested in 4.3). When I run the following code:

```
var options = {
    quality: 50,
    mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    allowEdit: false,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
    correctOrientation: true
};

navigator.camera.getPicture(function (imageData) {
    console.log(imageData);
}, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
}, options);
```

The error callback is **instantly fired** and prints "No Image Selected" to console. That is: the camera app is opened and the error callback is fired while the camera is opened, before I take a picture.

But this same code works on devices with new Android versions (tested on an Android 7.0 device).

I'm using:

- Cordova 8.0
- cordova-android 6.4.0
- cordova-plugin-camera 4.0.2

Have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878963/ionic-cordova-camera-plugin-error-on-android), but getting the same result. So, how can I solve this issue? Am I forgetting something?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After two days of working on this and 30 minutes after this post on StackOverflow, the issue was **solved** following the steps described in this [GitHub comment](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/issues/263#issuecomment-373455199):

1. Add the following line to your config.xml: `<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTop" />`
2. Remove the directory `platforms/android/`
3. Run `ionic cordova prepare android`

Seems that the issue is caused by the installation of `cordova-plugin-background-mode` plugin, which I'm using too.

Comment: But i had problems using `singleTop` in combination with `cordova-plugin-deeplinks` and `cordova-plugin-camera`. https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en helped to understand `launchMode` in general. And https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin/issues/37#issuecomment-312845139 recommends to use `singleTask` to enable deep linking and camera usage. So far i can tell that `singleTask` does the trick in Android 4.4+.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed Issue by : Add the following line to your `config.xml` :

```kotlin
< preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTop" />
```

Note : Please check App if you use Appsflyer onelink for deeplinking.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve it by removing allowEdit: true

```
const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      correctOrientation: true,
      // allowEdit: true
    }
```